# jQuery .toggle() not working

Tags: jquery

The code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#new_opt').click(function() {  
        $('#reg_form').toggle('slow');  
    });  
});
```

Using Firefox.
First time I click, it shows, but then it doesn't hide when I click after that.

CSS:

```
#reg_form - display: none;
```

If it helps -

```
#new_opt - cursor: pointer;
```

When I click the first time the cursor is pointer and it shows but after that the cursor doesn't become a pointer too. weird.

Comment: If you can, show us before and after pics, annotated with your expectations. (What, a guy can dream, can't he?)

Comment: Are both ids or classes the new_opt and _reg_form , that also matters.

Comment: please provide the html related to new_opt and reg_form and css related to that , the display type also matters.

Comment: *long shot* -- Do you mean "show"?

Comment: Seems it should work.. Perhaps you could publish an example exhibiting the behavior?

Comment: @sussangitta , see the below example it works perfect http://jsfiddle.net/tASpA/ , i got the example from jquery only

Comment: @everybody - what could be the possible problem?

Comment: @sussas , do one thing in the firstclick , try open firebug console and see if there any errors , it might be throwing error and stopped working from there.

Comment: @sussas , if you have time go to jsfiddle and copy respective stuff in the given areas and provide US the link , the users from stackoverflow will fix in less than seconds , there are lot expertise people here.

Comment: @gov - how do you explain the cursor: pointer weird behaviour.

Comment: @sussag , i suspect something is breaking after the first click , check the firebug console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the div(#reg_form) that was loading had some part of it covering the #new_opt div hence the cursor not changing to a pointer and the toggle() not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#reg_form').hide();
    $('#new_opt').click(function() {  
        $('#reg_form').toggle('slow');  
    });  
});
```

and remove that CSS.

Comment: @Sussagittikasusa. Please link to a page where we can see the issue. Or do it in jsfiddle.

Comment: @ Sussag please either edit your question with full html ,css or create a jsfiddle link , why to do hit and trail , we can easliy fix the problem if you can provide the code